# Multiple plot side by side in R markdown is not user friendly

Tags: r, r-markdown

**Requirement within R Markdown**

1. Show Pie chart of data
2. Show data side by side and readable

I am doing it by 'par' and 'mfrow', here the code with example data

````
```{r warning=F, message=F, echo=F, fig.width=5, fig.height=4}
per <- c(36,23,13,4,9,15)
ct <- c(36,23,13,4,9,15)
name <- c('MS', 'Google', 'Amazon', 'FB', 'IBM', 'AliBaba')
frame <- data.frame(per,ct,name)
par( mfrow = c(1,2))
pie(frame$ct, frame$name, col = rainbow(length(frame$ct)))
grid.table(frame)

```
````

The issue with the code, both the plot override each other 
[image]

Now when I edit and change figure width then override issue has been fixed but text size reduced to non-readable

````
```{r warning=F, message=F, echo=F, fig.width=25, fig.height=20}
    per <- c(36,23,13,4,9,15)
    ct <- c(36,23,13,4,9,15)
    name <- c('MS', 'Google', 'Amazon', 'FB', 'IBM', 'AliBaba')
    frame <- data.frame(per,ct,name)
    par( mfrow = c(1,2))
    pie(frame$ct, frame$name, col = rainbow(length(frame$ct)))
    grid.table(frame)
```
````

[image]

Can someone please suggest any better approach or the way I make the second plot text more readable and visible.

Comment: You can't easily use `par(mfrow=...` with `grid.table`, since `grid.table` uses grid graphics, and `par(mfrow` affects base plots. `pie`, I assume, is also base graphics. This is why `kable` below works better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This solution is from this [link](https://gist.github.com/jennybc/e9e9aba6ba18c72cec26#file-2015-03-02_plot-next-to-table-rmd) which is supposed to be taken from a post here in SO, but I could not find the original post.
2. I used `knitr::kable()` instead of `grid.table()` for the table. You can modify the table to your liking later on.

---

````
<style type="text/css">
.twoC {width: 100%}
.clearer {clear: both}
.twoC .table {max-width: 50%; float: right}
.twoC img {max-width: 50%; float: left}
</style>

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
per <- c(36,23,13,4,9,15)
ct <- c(36,23,13,4,9,15)
name <- c('MS', 'Google', 'Amazon', 'FB', 'IBM', 'AliBaba')
frame <- data.frame(per,ct,name)
```
<div class="twoC">
```{r results = 'asis', echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(frame)
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
pie(frame$ct, frame$name, col = rainbow(length(frame$ct)))
```
</div>
<div class="clearer"></div>
````

[image]